# /gremlin/status endpoint not enabled on Neptune cluster (Error: no gremlin script supplied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

Making a get request to *https://my-neptune-endpoint:port/gremlin/status*
returns the below response instead of the expected result mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-api-status.html).

```
{
  "requestId": <request_id>,
  "code": "MissingParameterException",
  "detailedMessage": "no gremlin script supplied"
}
```

Intended response is of the form:

```
{
  "acceptedQueryCount": 9,
  "runningQueryCount": 1,
  "queries": [
    {
      "queryId": "fb34cd3e-f37c-4d12-9cf2-03bb741bf54f",
      "queryEvalStats": {
        "waited": 0,
        "elapsed": 23,
        "cancelled": false
      },
      "queryString": "g.V().addV()"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recently added Neptune feature for a release that is still in the process of rolling out to all regions. It should be available on your Neptune cluster within a few days.

Comment: I'm having this issue when calling the export service endpoint, but the documentation doesn't even mention how to specify this script:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-data-export.html